# When is a @JsonCreator method required for parsing?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

When I try to parse the following object:

```
@Data
public final class User implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("alias")
    private final String alias;
}
```

I get the error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `microservices.book.multiplication.domain.User` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `microservices.book.multiplication.domain.User` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 10]
```

And I solved this by adding a creator to the User class like this:

```
@Data
public final class User implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("alias")
    private final String alias;


    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("alias") String alias){
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

This works fine.

So now I go and parse the following object:

```
@Data
public final class Multiplication implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("factorA")
    private final Integer factorA;
    @JsonProperty("factorB")
    private final Integer factorB;
}
```

and I don't get an error... why? why it doesn't require me to use a constructor here?

Here's the class where the parsing takes place

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.controller;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.Multiplication;
import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.MultiplicationResultAttempt;
import microservices.book.multiplication.controller.MultiplicationResultAttemptController.ResultResponse;
import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.User;
import microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;



import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MultiplicationResultAttemptController.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MultiplicationResultAttemptControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    MultiplicationService multiplicationService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private JacksonTester<MultiplicationResultAttempt> jsonResult;
    private JacksonTester<ResultResponse> jsonResponse;

    @BeforeAll
    void initAll(){
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
    }

    @Test
    public void postResultReturnCorrect() throws Exception{
        genericParameterizedTest(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void postResultReturnNotCorrect() throws Exception{
        genericParameterizedTest(true);
    }

    void genericParameterizedTest(final Boolean correct) throws Exception{
        given(multiplicationService.checkAttempt(any(MultiplicationResultAttempt.class))).willReturn(correct);
        User user = new User("Smith");
        Multiplication multiplication = new Multiplication(50,70);
        MultiplicationResultAttempt attempt = new MultiplicationResultAttempt(user, multiplication, 3500);

        // when
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(
                post("/results").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                        content(jsonResult.write(attempt).getJson())).
                andReturn().getResponse();

        // then
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(
                jsonResponse.write(new ResultResponse(correct)).getJson());
    }
}
```

Comment: *@JsonCreator is used to fine tune the constructor or factory method used in deserialization.*

Comment: Are you compiling your `User` class with Java method parameter names included (and including the Jackson JDK8 module so it knows how to see them)?

Comment: Note also that you can set your Lombok configuration to [`lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), which will add an annotation to the constructor with the necessary mappings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `alias` of your `User` is marked as `final`, which means it can't be initialized through a setter. Because in order to assign a value to the field through a setter it should be already initialized with the default value (`null`, `0`, `false` depending on the type), but `final` variable **can't be reassigned**.

**Reminder:** the mechanism which Jackson uses by default is to instantiate the class using *no-args* constructor and then assign the fields via setters. But it can't be done if one of the fields is `final`, they such fields need to be provided through constructor, because `final` means - "assign only once".

#### There are two ways to instruct Jackson to use a parametrized constructor:

**1.** The first option is to point at the constructor explicitly by annotating it with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) and apply `@JsonProperty` on each of the constructor arguments as specified in the documentation.

**2.** Another option is to add a dependency to *Jackson Modules: Java 8* ([link to Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-modules-java8/2.13.3)), which is an umbrella multi-module that consists of several modules including [Parameter names module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-names).

And then you need to configure `ObjectMapper`. For that, you need to place `ParameterNamesModule` as a Bean into the Spring's Context, and it would be grabbed at the application start-up and applied while `ObjectMapper` would be configured.

```
@Bean
public ParameterNamesModule parameterNamesModule() {
    return new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES);
}
```

But there's a **caveat**. A quote from the documentation of the [`JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.Mode.html#PROPERTIES):

> Mode that indicates that the argument(s) for creator are to be bound from matching properties of incoming Object value, using creator argument names (explicit or implicit) to match incoming Object properties to arguments.
>
> **Note** that this mode is currently (2.5) always used for
> multiple-argument creators; the **only ambiguous case is that of a
> single-argument creator**.

I.e. this option would not work if your constructor has **exactly one** argument.

To make the Jackson recognize a *single-arg constructor*, you need to apply `@JsonProperty` on the argument.

This behavior explained [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-name) and also mentioned in the [module-description](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-names) at the very bottom of the page:

> **Preconditions:**
>
> - if class Person has a single argument constructor, its argument needs to be annotated with `@JsonProperty("propertyName")`. This is to
>   **preserve legacy behavior**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the documentation you quote is several versions out of date, and Jackson is quite happy to use a singleton constructor without annotations **if** parameter names are included: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- There's still an issue with a single-arg constructor even after registering `ParameterNamesModule` (see the quote from the documentation). I've tested it exhaustively. If constructor has a least 2 arguments, no data-binding annotations required, but with a single-arg constructor deserialization would fail.